# How to store the list of installed Android applications into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I got a list of installed applications and I want to put them into an ArrayList(for filtering purposes) organized in this way - AppName, PackageName, Icon.

The closest reference that I can find is this but I don't understand how to implement this / (use this class and methods) into my code. Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system     packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }

        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Here is the code that i am currently working on.

```
public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>{

private List<ApplicationInfo> appList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;

public AppAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ApplicationInfo> objects){
    super(context, resource,objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.appList= objects;
    packageManager= context.getPackageManager();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = convertView;
    if(null == view){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_app,null);
    }

    ApplicationInfo data = appList.get(position);

    if(null != data){
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconView.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
    return view;
}

public int getCount(){
    return((null != appList) ? appList.size() : 0);
}
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position){
    return((null != appList) ? appList.get(position): null);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Comment: That code snippet looks like it accomplishes exactly what you want. What is the exact issue you're having? We can't help if you don't have any of your code listed.

Comment: How can i implement this into my current code? Do i have to create a new class or can i just add it on top of my current code and named it Class App above my AppAdapter method?
I have added my code.

Comment: The `PInfo` class looks like a duplicate of your own `ApplicationInfo` class. I would put the top code snippet into the adapter class for now and replace `PInfo` with `ApplicationInfo`

Comment: I do not have ApplicationInfo class. Upon implementation, i have encountered the following errors:

1) Class ApplicationInfo - 'ApplicationInfo' is already defined in this compilation unit
2) Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode); - cannot resolve method 'v(java.lang.String)'
3) getPackageManager() - cannot resolve method 'getPackageManager()'